# Why CMake recompile all library sources when only options for one file changed?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, recompile

So, I have simple project with library compiled from two sources and executable with depends on this library:

```
./a.cpp
#include "a.h"
int a() {
    return X;
}

./a.h
int a();

./b.cpp
#include "b.h"
int b() {
    return 2;
}

./b.h
int b();

./c.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
int c() {
    return a() + b();
}

int main() {
    return c();
}

./c.h
int c();

./CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set_property(
    SOURCE a.cpp
    APPEND
    PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
    "X=${X}"
)
add_library(ab a.cpp b.cpp)
add_executable(c c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c ab)
```

I compile it by (inside build dir)

```
cmake .. -DX=4
make
```

Then I want to change X to 5, I do

```
cmake .. -DX=5
make
```

I expect file `a.cpp` to be recompiled, and `ab` and `c` to be relinked (because they both depend on this cpp file), but I expect no recompilation of other cpp's because their compilation options didn't change and they do not depend on `a.cpp`

What I get is that `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are both recompiled (and `c.cpp` is correctly not recompiled)

So my questions are:

- Is it expected behaviour. If so, why?
- How do I structure the project, so that changing compile options for 1 file will not recompile each file in the library?

Tried CMake 3.5.1 on Linux and CMake 3.7.2 on MacOS

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is expected. CMake doesn't generate dependency info for macros, as they're too complicated to deal with.

It's possible to [generate](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) multiple config files; in this way it's treated as simple header timestamp dependencies.